# CSS Percentage Bars

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make a SIMPLE Css percent bar.

OK go to http://htmledit.squarefree.com/
and copy/paste this in it:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>

<style>
#perc {
width:667px;
border:4px solid blue;
}
#perc_in {
width:100%;
padding:3px;
font-size:17pt;
background:red;
margin:3px;
}
</style>

</head>
<body>
<div id="perc"><div id="perc_in">100%</div></div>
</body>
</html>
```

As you can see the red inside bar is overlapping the blue border... why? :\

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By the W3C box model, margins and padding add to the width of a `<div>`. So instead of 100%, the width becomes more than that, and causes the progress bar to overflow the blue border.

You'll have to change the 3px margin of `#perc_in` to a 3px padding on `#perc`, and remove the padding on `#perc_in`.

Here is the updated code (added by Blaenk):

```
#perc {
    width:667px;
    border:4px solid blue;
    padding:3px;
}

#perc_in {
    width:100%;
    font-size:17pt;
    background:red;
}
```

Comment: Hope you don't mind I added the added the code for you, tested and works.

Comment: Ah great - great. Forgot about padding/margins.

Comment: @Blaenk: thanks, looks good to me. I should also remove the part about stretching `#perc` because it doesn't sound right.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is: [W3C box model](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html). It says that final width of an element is a sum of `width` and `padding` properties. So if you declare that element suppose to have `width: 100%` (to be exact: 667 pixels in this case) and also declare that element should have 3-pixel padding from left and right (total: 6 px) the final width of the element is: `667 + 3 + 3 = 673` pixels.